# Background Transfer Service: Resuming Redirected Request

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

Download tasks submitted to an NSURLSession with a background session configuration will, to my understanding, be automatically reattempted by the OS without intervention from the submitting app.

However, if the original download task redirects to a new URL, and that request fails, when the OS reattempts/resumes the download task will it reattempt the original request (NSURLSessionTask.originalRequest) or the subsequent redirected request (NSURLSessionTask.currentRequest)?

Does anyone have experience with this case?